# Trouble getting button to show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript.  I have a checkbox list that looks great, but I'm trying to add a button to it so that when the user is done checking, the button is hit, and then my function is called to figure out what is checked and also what is not checked.

However, my button is missing.  I tried adding the code within li tags with the rest of the checkbox part, but it didn't show up.  I tried adding it after the dd tag and also after the end of the div.  I think I have to keep it within the form tag for my function to work, unless I'm mistaken.  Any ideas why the button isn't showing up?

[This](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-value-selected-checkboxes_cs) is the example I found the function idea in.  I searched on the internet and can't find any good ideas why my button doesn't show up.  It's probably a syntax error with the tab or something.

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.

-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Michele Project</title>
        <link href="css/skins/polaris/polaris.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/demo/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="js/icheck.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass:'icheckbox_polaris',
                    radioClass:'iradio_polaris',
                    increaseArea:'10%'
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Returns an array with values of the selected (checked) checkboxes in "frm"
        function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
            // JavaScript & jQuery Course - http://coursesweb.net/javascript/
            var selchbox = [];        // array that will store the value of selected checkboxes

            // gets all the input tags in frm, and their number
            var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;

            // traverse the inpfields elements, and adds the value of selected (checked) checkbox in selchbox
            for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
                if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
            }

            return selchbox;
        }

        document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function() {
            var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);
            alert(selchb);
        }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            ul {list-style-type: none}
            img {padding-right: 20px; float:left}
            #infolist {width:500px}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="skin skin-line">
        <div class="arrows">
          <div class="top" data-to="skin-flat"></div>
          <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-polaris"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="skin skin-polaris">
        <div class="arrows">
          <div class="top" data-to="skin-line"></div>
          <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-futurico"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Select Items for Column Headings</h3>
        <dl class="clear">
          <dd class="selected">
            <div class="skin-section">
              <h4>Live</h4>

              <ul class="list">
                <li>
                  <input tabindex="21" type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-1">
                  <label for="polaris-checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>

                </li>
                <li>
                  <input tabindex="22" type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-2" checked>
                  <label for="polaris-checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-3" >
                  <label for="polaris-checkbox-3">Checkbox 3</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="polaris-checkbox-4" checked >
                  <label for="polaris-checkbox-4">Checkbox 4</label>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </div>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.skin-polaris input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
                radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
                increaseArea: '20%'
              });
            });
            </script>

           $('#checkbox').prop('checked')  

          </dd>

        </dl>
      </div>
     <input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" /> //this button isnt showing up on web page
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: I created a fiddle here and the button is visible:  http://jsfiddle.net/2pDM5/

Comment: I wonder why it isn't showing up for me?  That's weird!  Maybe it has to do with the polaris plugin hiding something?  I don't see the polaris stuff in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks!  I got it showing up now.  I refreshed my page and commented out the $('#checkbox').prop('checked')